# docker sharing host directory

Tags: windows, docker

I used to share my host diretory with a docker container with the command (osx):

```
docker run --name tensorflower -it -p 8888:8888 -v /c/foo/labs:/home tensorflow/tensorflow
```

on windows it used to work with:

```
docker run --name tensorflower -it -p 8888:8888 -v //c/foo/labs:/home tensorflow/tensorflow
```

But now it does not work on windows. I tried both `-v` variants. As I do not get any error messages, I have no glue where to dig in to solve the problem.

How can I share the host directory `c:\foo\labs` with my docker container? 
Or at least get some more informaton regarding the error?

Docker version 17.09.1-ce, build 19e2cf6 on windows 10

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to test it, but wouldn't `-v "c:\foo\labs":/home tensorflow/tensorflow` work for you ?

Comment: @Aserre tried ``-v  "c:\foo\labs:/home"`` and  ``-v  "c:\foo\labs":/home``. Still not shareing the host directory ``c:\foo\labs`` in the container under ``/home``

Comment: From ``Docker > settings > Shared Drives`` the format is stated ``docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data``. I tried with ``c:/foo/labs:/home`` but no effect. In the settings, the Drive ``C`` is marked as shared.

Comment: When you say "no effect", what do you mean ? Do you get an error message ? Have you tried connecting to your container and running `find / -name somefile_in_your_labs_folder` ?

Comment: Hi. no effec = ``ls /home`` which list only ``., ..``. I do not get error message, on each of the variants. I did a ``find`` but with no results.

Comment: When the container is Windows Server Core 2016, this works:
docker run -v c:/hostfolder/:c:\containerfolder -it  testcontainer cmd
(just checked with host Win10 17.09.0-ce)
Your container is OSX? Have you tried -v c:/foo/labs/:/home/foobar ?

Comment: Container is ubunut-linux